# Как изменить границы именованного диапазона?

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

Есть именованный диапазон. Если вхожу в *Формулы/Диспетчер имён*, то функция "удалить" на заданном диапазоне неактивна, а если жмём "изменить", то неактивно поле самого диапазона, изменить можно только имя.

Нигде в формулах не используется, лист не защищён.

Что ещё может мешать его изменить? Любой другой диапазон спокойно изменяется...

Comment: Покажите пример

Comment: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/5xzx/48KfaEpiz
там диапазон tMain такой "глючный" по каким-то причинам

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Имя умной таблицы. Это видно и по ярлычку в диспетчере имен - ярлык в виде таблицы.

Причем диапазон умной таблицы задан на часть таблицы. Видимо, кто-то игрался или умная таблица создана случайно.

Диапазон умной таблицы редактировать нельзя, он изменяется сам при добавлении/удалении строк.

Преобразовать умную таблицу в обычную: ПКМ на таблице, в меню выбрать *Таблица - Преобразовать в диапазон*. Именованный диапазон удалится.

Создать умную таблицу: выделить диапазон, вкладка *Вставка - Таблица*. Будет создан новый именованный диапазон.

Comment: Это я по незнанию задал, видимо... Всегда думал, что все диапазоны имеют такое свойство автоподстраиваться. Спасибо!